How do i I do a mutual close of a channel with a higher fee on Core Lightning after from the state CLOSINGD_COMPLETE?
I attempted to close one of my channels today by running:
lightning-cli -k close id=******* unilateraltimeout=10800 feerange=[1000,4000]
I got the following output:
         # Sending closing fee offer 424sat, with range 151sat-600sat
# Received closing fee offer 424sat, with range 424sat-424sat
{
   "tx": "*******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************",
   "txid": "***************************************************",
   "type": "mutual"
}


After a couple of hours the transaction is still unconfirmed onchain.
I tried to close the same channel again with a higher fee: lightning-cli -k close id=******* unilateraltimeout=10800 feerange=[3000,5000] but I got this error:
{
   "code": -32602,
   "message": "id: Channel in state CLOSINGD_COMPLETE: invalid token (see logs for details)"
}


The log, .lightning/bitcoin/log shows:
2024-12-15T13:54:28.075Z INFO    lightningd: JSON COMMAND close: Invalid parameter id (Channel in state CLOSINGD_COMPLETE): token '"******x****x*"'

Below are the channels state changes and status as show by the output of listchannels:
 "state_changes": [
            {
               "timestamp": "2024-08-14T06:27:46.645Z",
               "old_state": "CHANNELD_AWAITING_LOCKIN",
               "new_state": "CHANNELD_NORMAL",
               "cause": "user",
               "message": "Lockin complete"
            },
            {
               "timestamp": "2024-12-15T08:55:13.190Z",
               "old_state": "CHANNELD_NORMAL",
               "new_state": "CHANNELD_SHUTTING_DOWN",
               "cause": "user",
               "message": "User or plugin invoked close command"
            },
            {
               "timestamp": "2024-12-15T08:55:13.552Z",
               "old_state": "CHANNELD_SHUTTING_DOWN",
               "new_state": "CLOSINGD_SIGEXCHANGE",
               "cause": "user",
               "message": "Start closingd"
            },
            {
               "timestamp": "2024-12-15T08:55:13.952Z",
               "old_state": "CLOSINGD_SIGEXCHANGE",
               "new_state": "CLOSINGD_COMPLETE",
               "cause": "user",
               "message": "Closing complete"
            }
         ],
         "status": [
            "CHANNELD_NORMAL:Reconnected, and reestablished.",
            "CLOSINGD_SIGEXCHANGE:We agreed on a closing fee of 424 satoshi for tx:***********************************************************"
         ],


What could I do to solve this issue? Can the state CLOSINGD_COMPLETE of the channel change to a new state that would allow me to attempt to close the channel with a higher fee?
